Purpose of each matrix in Johansen cointegration test
Trying to migrate Johansen cointegration test to .NET but can't find clear steps in the algorithm. The source code takes some space, so for now I'll post links and excerpts but can add more upon request.
This is implementation in Python that I believe was used by everyone before statsmodels
https://github.com/iisayoo/johansen/blob/master/johansen/johansen.py
This is current implementation in .NET
https://github.com/Indemos/Terminal/blob/main/Core/Services/CointegrationService.cs
public static double Johansen(Matrix<double> Y)
{
  // Step 1: First difference of Y
  var dY = Lag(Y, 1);

  // Step 2: Create lagged Y (Y_{t-1}, ..., Y_{t-lags})
  var lagY = Lag(Y, 10);

  // Step 3: Compute residuals from OLS of dY on laggedY
  var beta = OLS(lagY, dY);  // β = (X'X)^(-1) X'Y
  var dYhat = lagY * beta;
  var residuals = dY - dYhat;

  // Step 4: Compute covariance matrices 
  var covMatrix = GetCovMatrix(residuals, lagY)
  var evd = covMatrix.Evd();
  var eigenValues = evd.EigenValues.Real();

  // Step 6: Compute Trace and Max-Eigenvalue statistics
  var traceTests = eigenValues.Select(o => -Math.Log(1 - o)).ToList();
  var traceStat = traceTests.Sum();

  // Step 7: Compare trace statistics with critical values to determine cointegration rank
  // github.com/iisayoo/johansen/blob/master/johansen/critical_values.py
  // Critical values for Johansen's Trace test at a 95% confidence level
  var criticalValues = new double[] { 2.98, 4.13, 6.94, 10.47, 12.32, 16.36 };
  var cointegrationRank = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < traceTests.Count; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(traceTests[i] + " > " + criticalValues[i]);
    if (traceTests[i] > criticalValues[i]) cointegrationRank++;
  }

  return cointegrationRank;
}

Questions

There are around 5 matrices created during the test (first diff, lag, beta, residuals, covariance) but it looks like all of them are only used to create covariance matrix between residuals and lagged matrix and use its eigenvalues to define how strong cointegration is between provided time series. So, at the end I need only one matrix of covariances, correct?

If assumption #1 is correct, what is the logic behind comparing residuals to lagged matrix? To me, residuals seem like an error / deviation from the selected beta / regression / ols line and lagged matrix is supposed to capture long-term / trend part of the original matrix of time series. What is the point to compare trend and noise / fluctuations? How is it supposed to detect any cointegration if they're just part of decomposed / detrended original time series?



I guess you have to read the Johansen article(s) or a text book. Rephrasing everything is a lot of work (unless someone has readily available teaching notes).
